# Create new xcode project from command line

Tags: xcode, terminal

I want to create iPhone application with native apple frameworks. But I want to create it from command line. Please help. Thanks

Comment: So you want to write an iOS app using command line tools, or you want to generate an Xcode project using the command line? The two are not even close.

Comment: I want to generate an Xcode project using command line

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/q/3518719/1538079

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Xcode project from command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518719/creating-xcode-project-from-command-line)

Answer (score 14):

```
pod lib create ProjectName
```

This will create XCode project library, sample and UnitTests.

Answer (score -1):

there is no ready-made tool to do this but you can use another project as a template, copy it, rename it and its targets/settings (it's all XML so you can parse and modify it, but for simplicity I would try to use a project template in which you  only have to exchange some names :))

Comment: i do it all the time ;) works fine :) but I will admit it is fragile and easy to break