# How to create ios Xcodeproject using terminal

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, terminal

Hello I wanted to write script for xcode project creation,building and running into emulator for generic development,I tried so many ways but no result,using terminal cordova(phonegap) is creating,building and running xcode project in emulator.How they are handling,please help me to resolve this.

If i create project through xcode how can i add html and image files to xcode using terminal

for building xcode project:

```
xcodebuild -target ‘AppName.xcodeproj’ -scheme ‘AppName’ -configuration “Debug/Release” -sdk iphoneos6.0/5.0/4.0 -arch “armv7 armv7s” CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=’BuildDirectoryName‘ ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO/YES
```

Comment: May be this help you out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3518719/creating-xcode-project-from-command-line

Comment: Did u check cordova documentation abt creating a project ?

Comment: I read documentation,internally they are using some xcodebuild commands